# Mongoexport stays at 0 percent

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have been trying to use mongoexport to get a csv file of a collection. I have done this before but I don't know why now I am getting the following error.

[Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uoKx.png)

Looks like it is able to log into the db but then it won't go beyond 0.0%. Any suggestions? I tried looking for an answer but had no luck.

I have also tried to specify csv and  with "--type=csv --fields=..." and got exactly the same error.

After I get the error my mongod service dies as shown in the following image.

[Mongod service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZNFP.png)

It shows as "activating" as I have an auto-restart on the service in case of a crash.

Comment: Where are you executing the `mongoexport`? Post the logs of your `mongod` instance as it might have information regarding why the DB died. Also, monitor your system resources when you are exporting the collection (specifically, Memory usage and CPU usage).

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to find the answer.

Turns out my database was corrupted, sadly had to restart populating it as I had no backup file at the time.

Now I do a backup file using mongoexport once per day.